# file does not get created in the application folder

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a simple text file in the application folder, as follows:

```
struct RegistrationView: View {
    init() {
        let fileURL = URL.documentsDirectory
            .appending(path: "test.txt")
        
        print(fileURL.absoluteString)
        let test = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        print(test)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
       Text("hello")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the file does not get created at all and the value of the variable of `test` is false.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the file path to the `createFile` method. Not the URL string. Try the following.

```
struct RegistrationView: View {
    init() {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test.txt")
        
        print(fileURL.path)
        let test = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        print(test)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake was `fileURL.absoluteString` instead of `fileURL.path`.